# Replace scripts inside 3rd party iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am using a 3rd party iframe who has its own scripts. My boss requested that I need change the inner scripts of the iframe. I spent most of my day researching about that, but I cannot find anything about that (at least that works). I need to put my own script inside the head of the iframe. Is it even posible solve this with javascript?

Comment: Can you add the code sample to elaborate the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible due to security reasons. If you can't access iframe source, you can't do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I only want to confirm my suspicions